# Proxy not working with PhantomJS. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am trying to use `phantomjs` using a proxy. The following code creates a snapshot of the page so that I could verify if the proxy is indeed working.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://checkip.org/', function (status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if (status === "success") {
        page.render('p1pexample.png');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I invoke the above code using:

```
 phantomjs pinit.js --proxy-type=http --proxy=zproxy.luminati.io:22225
       --proxy-auth=lum-customer-naluaa-zone-static:xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The snapshot shows the same IP as I would get without the proxy. What could be the reason for this? Am I using the proxy in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script file name must be the last in command line, otherwise proxy parameters are treated like arguments for the script.

```
 phantomjs --proxy-type=http --proxy=zproxy.luminati.io:22225
   --proxy-auth=lum-customer-naluaa-zone-static:xxxxxxxxxxxx pinit.js
```